# How to display data dynamically in perl?

Tags: perl, format

I have some data which i want to display the data dynamically on screen (CLI) like linux **top** command. Is there any Perl CPAN module or utility which can do this for me.

For time being, I am doing this using below code which does not seem so impressive to me -

```
my $thread;
$thread = threads->create( \&Read );

while (1) {
    sleep 1;
    system("clear");
    Display();
}
```

`Read()` method reads data from some file and display that data using `Display()` method.

Comment: How does the `Display()` subroutine look like? Why is it not impressive?

Comment: There was the problem of formatting and i used 'clear' command with Text::Format, and it solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Text::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Table-1.130/lib/Text/Table.pm) will do the job for you and give you desire output:

Here is the example:

```
use Text::Table;
my $tb = Text::Table->new(
    "Planet", "Radius\nkm", "Density\ng/cm^3"
      );
$tb->load(
    [ "Mercury", 2360, 3.7 ],
    [ "Venus", 6110, 5.1 ],
    [ "Earth", 6378, 5.52 ],
    [ "Jupiter", 71030, 1.3 ],
      );
print $tb;
```

This prints a table from the given title and data like this:

```
Planet  Radius Density
    km     g/cm^3
Mercury  2360  3.7
Venus    6110  5.1
Earth    6378  5.52
Jupiter 71030  1.3
```

Another module is [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Perl6-Form-0.005/lib/Perl6/Form.pm).